# change back button of UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have this code that changes the back button of my UINavigationBar

```
// Set the custom back button
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backag.png"];

//create the button and assign the image
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selback.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; 
button.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = NO;


//set the frame of the button to the size of the image (see note below)
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//create a UIBarButtonItem with the button as a custom view
UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;

// Cleanup
[customBarItem release];
```

If I put it in the viewDidLoad method it works fine. However, when I load the next view the old style button shows up. To fix this I tried putting this code in the next view's viewDidLoad method, but then no button is visible.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used tis code in both view and it's worked fine...

// add following code in your both view's viewDidLoad method...

```
UIButton *leftButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[leftButton1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Viewone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
leftButton1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[leftButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(yourclickevent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton1];
[leftButton1 release];

UIButton *leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ViewSecond.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
leftButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourclickevent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:leftButton];
[leftButton release];
```

Hope,this will help you...enjoy..

Answer (score 2):

Apply same code in

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you set the hidesBackButton property on the navigationItem:

```
// Setup custom back button
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```